# PHP DOM Why does removing a child node of an element with removeChild interrupt a foreach loop over its child nodes?

Tags: php, dom

I have encountered a puzzling behavior of the DOM method `removeChild`. When looping over the child nodes of a DOMElement, removing one of these nodes along the way interrupts the loop, i.e., the loop does not iterate over the remaining child nodes.

Here is a minimal example:

```
$test_string = <<<XML
<test>
<text>A sample text with <i>mixed content</i> of <b>various sorts</b></text>
</test>
XML;

$test_DOMDocument = new DOMDocument();
$test_DOMDocument->loadXML($test_string);
$test_DOMNode = $test_DOMDocument->getElementsByTagName("text");

foreach ($test_DOMNode as $text) {
  foreach ($text->childNodes as $node) {
    if (preg_match("/text/", $node->nodeValue)) {
      echo $node->nodeValue;
      $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    } else {
      echo $node->nodeValue;
    }
  }
}
```

If I comment out the line `$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);`, then the output is the entire test string, i.e., `A sample text with mixed content of various sorts`, as expected. With that line, however, only the first child node is output, i.e., `A sample text with`. That is, removing the first child node as the loop passes over it apparently interrupts the loop; the remaining child nodes are not processed. Why is that?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Duplicate of this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310643/removing-childnodes-using-node-childnodes-foreach

Comment: @DaveS Closely related, but that's JS and this is PHP, so the solutions will be slightly different.

Comment: @DaveS Thank you for the link to the other post! I did not know that `childNodes` is a "live collection". It seems plausible that this is the cause of the behavior that I am seeing, although that behavior is not exactly the same as the one in the other post. What I am seeing is that, after removing a node, _none_ of the remaining nodes are processed, not only that some nodes are skipped. Anyway, how can I make the live collection static in PHP? I tried to put it in a variable before iterating over it, but that did not help.

Comment: Have you tried the same approach? work backwards from the end of each collection so removing nodes has no effect on the part of the lists that hasn't been processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing the suggestions of the comments on my question, I came up with the following solution:

```
$test_string = <<<XML
<test>
<text>A sample text with <i>mixed content</i> of <b>various sorts</b></text>
</test>
XML;

$test_DOMDocument = new DOMDocument();
$test_DOMDocument->loadXML($test_string);
$test_DOMNode = $test_DOMDocument->getElementsByTagName("text");

foreach ($test_DOMNode as $text) {
  $child_nodes = $text->childNodes;
  for($n = $child_nodes->length-1; $n >= 0; --$n) {
    $node = $child_nodes->item($n);
    if (preg_match("/text/", $node->nodeValue)) {
      echo $node->nodeValue;
      $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    } else {
      echo $node->nodeValue;
    }
  }
}
```

That is, I go through the child nodes in reverse order, using a method suggested in [another posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837852/reversing-order-of-items-in-domnodelist). In this way, all nodes are processed: The output is `various sorts of mixed contentA sample text with`. Note the reverse order of the text fragments. In my specific use case, this reversal does not matter because I am not actually echoing the text nodes, but performing another kind of operation on them.